# Magento: how to get Website Payments Pro API log?

Tags: magento

May I have instructions for enabling API logging and instructions on how to access the log once it is enabled?

I have a problem with PayPal Website Payments Pro and PayPal support said:

“I need a copy of doDirectPayment API request and response so that I can test this for you.”

--

how to get Website Payments Pro API calls?

1. there is an “enable” on Debug Mode on Admin/PayPal/Website Payments Pro, so

1a. Does enabling Debug Mode on Website Payments Pro effect the customers ability to place orders ?

1b. Is enabling Debug Mode on Website Payments Pro all I need to do to get the API info?

1. In any case, where do i get the API info—for Website Payments Pro PayPal orders (aka Direct Payments)—once logging is on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1a. No

1b. You will see full requests and responses to payment system server in the log. Do you need something else.

1. In your var/log folder you will see file payment_[method name].log