# payapl issue on sandbox in magento

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I am working on website.where first i place real details for Paypal and its work.now  i put sandbox details for testing but i got error.

> PayPal gateway has rejected request. The totals of the cart item
>   amounts do not match order amounts (#10413: Transaction refused
>   because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for
>   details)

. I am using three currencies for site (USD,EURO,British pound). Can anyone help me why i got this error ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is pretty straight forward.  Need to look at the raw API request getting sent so you can see the values for AMT, ITEMAMT, TAXAMT, HANDLINGAMT, and SHIPPINGAMT.

ITEMAMT + TAXAMT + HANDLINGAMT + SHIPPINGAMT needs to total up to the value of AMT.  If it doesn't you'll end up with the error you're getting, so something about your cart details must not be calculating correctly.

Again, the best way to track this down is to get a look at the raw API request.

Comment: Thanks for your response.How can i get the raw API response ?

Comment: Review [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690613/magento-how-to-get-website-payments-pro-api-log).